# PNP Search Results Managed Columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp, pnp-search-webparts

I am looking to create a Knowledge base in SP for my company, the team doesn't just want to search in libraries, they want a more user friendly/ appealing search result. I have downloaded the PNP search app and added it to the App catalog, have it all set up to source data from the specific site we want, issue is they want to source managed metadata in the results, there is no option in managed columns that specifically relates to manager metadata. these managed metadata are for searching say Departments - IT or HR. they want the search results to then be sortable by this column, but I can't source it. any ideas which preset option I need to be using or how to write the handlebar expressions to source it.

[image] (Column in library as managed metadata)

[image] (PNP search results editor)

[image] (managed columns in editor)

Comment: Are you saying that you have content tagged with a Managed Metadata column called "Departments" but no metadata is showing in the search results? Did you check your search schema to make sure you have the right field name? 

Also did you check the "Selected properties" dropdown in the PnP Search Results web part to make sure you selected the correct fields there?

Comment: It does show with the search under summary but I am not able to filter the results for it to show in the PNP search results window.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an available refinable string in your search schema, then map your crawled property to it. Managed properties are not refinable or sortable by default and you cannot make a custom managed property refinable or sortable other than how I mentioned in the beginning of this answer. You used to be able to in the good old SharePoint on prem days, but not with SP Online. Once you map your crawled property (department) to the refinablestring, wait a bit and maybe even reindex your library. In about 15 to 30 mins, you should now see the refinablestring available in your managed column from the PnP Search web part.You will then use the refinablestring as the sorting field.